# How is random_batch deprecated in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deprecated, attributeerror

I was doing [this](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/02_Convolutional_Neural_Network.ipynb) tutorial and I got stuck at the line with `data.random_batch(batch_size=train_batch_size)`.
It's looking like there's been some deprecation in tensorflow. I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Datasets' object has no attribute 'random_batch'
```

I've been googling for a solution, but no luck. Does anyone know where this method hides now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tf.data.dataset.batch(batch_size = train_batch_size)` for batching the input data but for that frist you have to create a dataset from your input data by using the relevant method for your data for example `dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename)`. 
After that you can create an iterator to get each batch for training by defining an iterator `dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()`. A detailed explanation could be find on the tensorflow guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data)